# vector of pairs of intergers to just a vector of vector of integers

Tags: c++

How do I go from

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>
```

to just

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>>
```

? Is there a really efficient way of doing it?

Comment: You mean you have a vector of pairs and want to assign the contents to vector of vector?

Comment: @Aconcagua Yes please

Comment: Given that you have a fixed number of ints for the inner vector, you could also have `std::vector<int[2]>`. Assuming you don't intend to resize it, that is.

Comment: a vector of pair like that uses much less memory and is much faster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

int main()
{
    //Vector of pairs
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> pairs = { {1,1},{2,2} };
    //New vector
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec;
    //Allocate memory for new vector
    vec.reserve(pairs.size());

    for (auto &p : pairs)
    {
        //Create vector with first and second element of pair
        std::vector<int> v = { p.first, p.second };
        vec.push_back(v);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Update: to avoid copying you can move the vector into the new vector `vec.push_back(std::move(v));`.